# Haskell multiple declaration error type "Shape"

Tags: haskell

I trying to create an sum type named `Shape` and later on another sum type named `PositionedShape` with the property of Shape init

```
data Shape = Circle Float |
             Rectangle Float Float

area :: Shape -> Float
area (Circle r)      = pi * r * r
area (Rectangle h w) = h * w

data Point = Point Float Float
             deriving (Eq,Show )


data PositionedShape = Circle Point Float |
                       Rectangle Point Float Float
                       deriving (Eq,Show)
```

From me, it seem correct but it kept saying multiple declaration.

```
Week7.hs:92:24: error:
    Multiple declarations of ‘Circle’
    Declared at: Week7.hs:26:14
                 Week7.hs:92:24

   |
92 | data PositionedShape = Circle Point Float |
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Week7.hs:93:24: error:
    Multiple declarations of ‘Rectangle’
    Declared at: Week7.hs:27:14
                 Week7.hs:93:24
   |
93 |                        Rectangle Point Float Float
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, you have declared `Circle` and `Rectangle` multiple times. In Haskell, data constructors must have unique names, at least within the same module.

You can resolve the issue by giving the data constructors unambiguous names, e.g.:

```
data PositionedShape = PositionedCircle Point Float |
                       PositionedRectangle Point Float Float
                       deriving (Eq,Show)
```

The data constructors can also be used as functions. For example, you can view `PositionedCircle` as a function:

```
Prelude> :t PositionedCircle
PositionedCircle :: Point -> Float -> PositionedShape
```

You can call it with a `Point` and a `Float` value:

```
Prelude> PositionedCircle (Point 1 2) 3
PositionedCircle (Point 1.0 2.0) 3.0
```

Function names must be unique, because otherwise the compiler don't know which one you mean. That's the reason that data constructors must have unambiguous names.

---

It seems that the problem that you're really trying to solve is how to associate a position with a shape, which might be better done like this:

```
data PositionedShape = PositionedShape Point Shape deriving (Eq, Show)
```

You could use this alternative like this:

```
Prelude> PositionedShape (Point 1 2) (Circle 3)
PositionedShape (Point 1.0 2.0) (Circle 3.0)
```